# Oracle Application Express history

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Application Express. How can I get session history (like Recent SQL Commands) and save it to custom table?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no ability to download the history from SQL commands, nor is the underlying table exposed to you via a public view.  This is really such an obvious feature that is missing.

I have added it as a feature request, to be considered in a future release of Oracle APEX.